# Bootstrap Cards same width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, column-width, bootstrap-carousel, bootstrap-cards

I want my cards to cover the equal width of the screen, but my code below is as per content.

Tried <kbd>card-deck</kbd>, but it didn't helped.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.0-2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container p-3 bg-white rounded">

    <div class="row">

      <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">

        <div class="carousel-inner">



          <div class="carousel-item active">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">0-10</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">00</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">1-9</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">00</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">2-8</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">00</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">3-7</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">00</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="carousel-item ">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">4-6</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">00</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">5-5</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">00</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">6-4</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">00</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


              <div class="col-lg-3">
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">7-3</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">00</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>


            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
      </div>


    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want my cards to cover the equal width of the screen, but my code below is as per content.

Tried <kbd>card-deck</kbd>, but it didn't helped.

I want my cards to cover the equal width of the screen, but my code below is as per content.

Tried <kbd>card-deck</kbd>, but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

In the div block change `col-lg-3`  to `col-lg-auto` so that it will occupy equal widths on the screen

Comment: it's not on full screen. See: https://imgur.com/YPc8sh2

Comment: Add div with class card-deck  after container>row  at start and recheck the carousel div row

Comment: I am using `carousel` as well, could you please add a live demo here.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using .card-columns class like this:

```
<div class="card-columns">

    <div id="card1" class="card">
        
        <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="Card image cap">

        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">
                CARD 1 TITLE
            </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            CARD 1 BODY
        </div>

    </div>
    
    <div id="card2" class="card">
        
        <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="Card image cap">

        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">
                CARD 2 TITLE
            </h5>
        </div>

        <div class="card-body">
            CARD 2 BODY
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

> and remove **row** and **col** divs, card-columns class take care of the rest

Comment: live example of [card-columns](http://catalog.byethost11.com/search?search=%D9%BE%D8%A7%DA%A9%DA%86%D9%88%D8%A8)

Comment: I am using `carousel` as well, could you please add a live demo here.

Comment: @teneji just remove every **row** , **col-lg-3** and the **container** <div>, it should take the width of the screen.

Comment: @tenji a live demo [link](http://mdf061.gigfa.com/catalog?search=%D9%BE%D8%A7%DA%A9%DA%86%D9%88%D8%A8&p=%D8%A7%D9%85%20%D8%AF%DB%8C%20%D8%A7%D9%81&sort=code&arng=asc)